# How to consume REST in Spring/Java with JSON unnamed values?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, resttemplate

I am new to JSON and REST. I am using Spring's RestTemplate to consume JSON. I was able to do it with this JSON response with this API call: http://data.fcc.gov/api/block/find?latitude=39.9936&longitude=-105.0892&showall=false&format=json

JSON Response:

```
    {"Block":{"FIPS":"080130608005010"},"County":
    {"FIPS":"08013","name":"Boulder"},"State":
    {"FIPS":"08","code":"CO","name":"Colorado"},"status":"OK","executionTime":"8"}
```

However, when I take this FIPS code from this request and try to use it to request information from the census with this call: http://api.census.gov/data/2012/acs5?get=B19001_002E&for=tract:060800&in=state:08+county:013&key=

This is the JSON Response I get:

```
    [["B19001_002E","state","county","tract"],
    ["225","08","013","060800"]]
```

As you can see all of the 'variables' are unnamed and in arrays. I am not sure how to consume this using Spring's RestTemplate using a POJO.

This is the Java code I have (where URL is the string of the API Call):

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
CensusData cd = restTemplate.getForObject(URL, CensusData.class);
System.out.println("data: " + cd.getData());
```

Here is my POJO (CensusData):

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CensusData {

     @JsonProperty
    private List<List<String>> data;

    public String getData() {
        String str = "";
        for(List<String> list : data) {
            for(String s : list) {
                str += s;
                str += " ";
            }
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I don't know what to name "data" in my CensusData object, since the values are unnamed in the JSON response. So I get this exception thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of template.main.CensusData out of START_ARRAY token
```

Comment: It's an array of arrays, simulating a standard CSV file (where the first row contains the column names).  What is the difficulty with that?  (Hint:  The universe is not composed entirely of POJOs.)

Comment: I guess I am unfamiliar parsing Json any other way, could you recommend or link to any other methods of parsing Json that could work for my example? The link posted below by Dino Tw has proved helpful.

Comment: "Any other way" is the *normal* way, where you produce a "nest" of Lists and Maps instead of using Jacksonesque POJOs.  Go to json.org -- at the bottom of the page are about 20 Java JSON kits to choose from.

Comment: @HotLicks To be fair, this is Bad JSON.

Comment: @chrylis - Yes, it's not the most elegant JSON I've ever seen, but you have to work with what you've got.

Answer (score 2):

Using Gson https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ .

```
String result = getResponseFromServer(String url); //restful
Gson gson = new Gson();
String[][] str = gson.fromJson(result, String[][].class);
```

Answer (score 0):

The real issue is that you haven't expanded the variables to create the mappings. You need to create the object mappings for the [Census Data API: Variables.](http://api.census.gov/data/2012/acs5/variables.html) Further introspection of the request parameter for `B19001_002E`, expands to the definition and corresponding json for [Less than 10,000](http://api.census.gov/data/2012/acs5/variables/B19001_002E.json). Which contains the following definition.

```
{
    "name": "B19001_002E",
    "label": "Less than $10,000",
    "concept": "B19001.  Household Income",
    "predicateType": "int"
}
```

Once you've successfully created this POJO, you can then reference the responses and move on to the next challenge.

Answer (score -1):

The response from census is value array, there is no key-value object, you don't use POJO for the mapping. The ObjectMapper#readValue() from Jackson may help you make the parsing task easier. Look the section **Tree Model Example** in [JacksonInFiveMinutes](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes) for examples.